# 2200mAh powerbank with 7,4Wh lion battery inside

Tags: batteries

Out of curiosity have I opened the powerbank I got. (Nothing dangerous, could be normally screwed open.) Inside there was a 3,7V Li-Ion battery with 7,4Wh marking on it. 5V powerbank should be 2200mAh. Is it a scam or do I miss something?

7,4Wh on 3,7V battery means = 2000mAh at 3,7V. With boost converter => ~ 1300mAh.

Comment: They all cheat and refer to the battery capacity at battery voltage, not the 5 V output. 3.7*2.2=8.14 Wh.

Comment: So why is the 3,7V battery itself labeled to be 7,4Wh?

Comment: Battery manufacturer lie less than power bank manufacturers. Measure it and it’s probably below 7 Wh.

Comment: So a scam :P So the math is as easy as I thought... Still 2200 -> 1300 seems to be a bit harsh scam :D

Comment: The 2200 refers to the _battery capacity_ at _battery voltage_, but I still say it’s purposely misleading the consumers.

Comment: @winny But if the battery inside is 3,7V and is 7,4Wh it is till only 2000mAh, not 2200mAh. And if the powerbank is 5V it is not misleading, but straight lying.

Comment: That’s right. If you have the energy, you should file a class action lawsuit.

Comment: :D I got that powerbank for 1 cent as a bonus for buying headphones, the shop does not sell the powerbank anymore.